# Randomly selecting N number of items from a list, duplicates possible

Tags: python, random

I am trying to generate a list of random items from another list b. Duplicates are allowed. I cannot use random.sample because N can exceed the number of items in list b. 
I have written some code below:

```
def generate_random_sequence(n):
   population = []
   for i in xrange(n):
       b = random.choice(stuff)
       population.append(b)
```

However i am really concerned about it's performance as it will be performed a lot of times. Is there a method in Random library that performs this task? Or is there a more optimized way of doing this task?

Comment: Please show us how your lists look like.

Comment: Use `random.sample` instead

Comment: Using just the random module you can't do much better, though `population = [random.choice(stuff) for _ in xrange(n)]` is more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `random.choice` in `numpy` library:

```
In [3]: np.random.choice([1,5,6],10)
Out[3]: array([6, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 1, 6, 1, 6])
```

Comment: Yes, `random.sample` is the way to go, but you've used the `numpy` version here...